# Slider with issues only on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slider

I'm using a slider with 5 items, which are images with a title over it. Using Firefox or Safari it works the way it should but in Chrome, well, the title runs away or… I just can't explain what happens.

The HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><h3><a href="example.com" class="shadow">Title</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="example.com" class="shadow">Title</a></h3></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 162px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.shadow {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width: 142px;
    height: 113px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top:132px;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.gop.com.pt). Just click the second link named "projectos".

Sorry for any errors in my english, it's not my primary language.

Thanks in advance.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl) plugin for the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying you are using position:relateve for li elements but in the example you page it doesn't seem to exist.

```
.small-list-carousel li {
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 162px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

just add position:relative to this style and it should probably work.

Comment: Thanks for your time but It's already in the style.css, I doubled checked that. If that was the case I guess it wouldn't work in Firefox either.

Comment: Found the solution. At least works for now, just added !important to position: relative. Don't know how or why.. but it works.